# how to double-click on a cell in table with Selenium Ruby Webdriver

Tags: ruby, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use below codes to double-click on a cell in a table in my web application (I tried to do Click two times with the hope that they are equal to double-click). However, the cell is not clicked at all, but I expect that after double-clicking on the cell, the text field will be displayed for me to edit info of that cell.

```
@driver.find_element(:xpath => "//table[@id='gridabc']//tr[1]/td[9]").click
@driver.find_element(:xpath => "//table[@id='gridabc']//tr[1]/td[9]").click
```

I'm using **Selenium Ruby Webdriver**. Please help guide me a way to resolve this. Thanks much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#@example Double click an element

el = driver.find_element(:id, "some_id")
driver.action.double_click(el).perform
```

Code shamelessly copied from the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder#double_click-instance_method) :)

Comment: it works well for me, Thanks so much and especially big thanks for pointing me to the source link: http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/b/bbc-selenium-webdriver-1.17.0/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html#method-i-double_click.