# Ruby Webdriver ActionClass double_click Not Working

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, double-click

I found a similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775467/how-to-double-click-on-a-cell-in-table-with-selenium-ruby-webdriver/16775560#16775560?newreg=f405fe29748c4e638b9dfcda9c2da735) and followed the example, but the solution appears to not be working.

I am trying to double click on an element using the documentation found [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder#double_click-instance_method).

I have the following code:

```
@article_zone = @driver.find_element(:id, "nbviewer-zone-overlay-13B27E79C7BC32F1").attribute("id")
```

Which assigns `@article_zone = "nbviewer-zone-overlay-13B27E79C7BC32F1"`

I then have the next line of code:

`@driver.action.double_click("id=" + @article_zone).perform`

But this line is throwing the following error:
`Error: TypeError: expected Selenium::WebDriver::Element, got "id=nbviewer-zone-overlay-13B27E79C7BC32F1":String`

The element `id=nbviewer-zone-overlay-13B27E79C7BC32F1` is what I am trying to double click. I am at a loss as to why I am receiving this error.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks for looking!

Comment: Saying something “appears to not be working” is not enough. Why doesn't the existing solution work?

Comment: Good question - that is what I am trying to determine. It appears I have followed the examples correctly but am receiving the error still. The existing solutions post says it worked, so I am trying to determine what may be wrong with my situation as it has been over a year since that post and things may have changed that I cannot pinpoint (versions/drivers/etc.)... I am a newbie to this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because `double_click` **by default tries to click in the middle of the element**. When I inspect the element, the middle of it is hidden below the "fold". To get around this, I can move to the element with an offset (from top left) and perform a double click in place:

```
@driver.action.move_to(@article, 10, 10).double_click.perform
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
@driver.action.double_click("id=" + @article_zone).perform
```

You call the `+` method on an instance of `String`. That is going to try to implicitly convert `@article_zone` into a string and append it to `"id="`. That string is then being handed to the `double_click` method, which is expecting an instance of `Selenium::WebDriver::Element`.

I suspect that if you remove `"id=" +` you would be okay:

```
@driver.action.double_click(@article_zone).perform
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response here - when I try that I get the same error. `Error: TypeError: expected Selenium::WebDriver::Element, got "nbviewer-zone-overlay-13B27E79C7BC32F1":String` I suspected it was not liking it as a `String` based on the error, but am not sure how to convert it to the `Selenium::WebDriver::Element` that it's looking for.

Comment: I also tried the first line of code without the `attribute` like this `@article_zone = @driver.find_element(:id, "nbviewer-zone-overlay-13B27E79C7BC32F1")` but that assigns `@article_zone` as `#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..f3c886a24 id="0.3165787053371305-3">`. This doesn't throw an error - but also doesn't perform the double-click. It basically skips that step doing nothing.

Comment: @GabrielKlueh Well that's the right object type, so that's what you want. You've moved to the next stage of the process: figuring out why you're not getting the expected result from `double_click`. You can't just hand it garbage and expect it to start working. ;)

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying the right object type is the latter (2nd comment I posted)? (i.e. #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..f3c886a24 id="0.3165787053371305-3">)

Comment: @GabrielKlueh Yes.